# How to handle locked accounts in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

I'm developing a web application for the deacons in my church. And while I have a good deal of experience coding in several languages, I have yet had to do any serious database modeling until deciding to tackle this need for my organization.

I'm very familiar with writing sql/ddl queries on existing database in (strictly mysql console, Spring MVC, Boot, Java, etc.). But, not since college have I had to consider normalization, 2nf, 3nf, 1:1, 1: many, etc... It's been a humbling experience, to say the least, trying to refresh my memory with the database theories learned years before and attempting to apply the concepts.

I created a model that seems, at least to me, to fit the needs of the users

My specific question is about locked accounts. I did read several posts about it, which only confused me more about how to approach this concept with my given data model? I really would appreciate any other suggestions and/or critiques; I definitely understand the concept and power of learning by failure.... Thanks.

**Use Case** :

```
1. Users holding office in a particular year can sign into the web 
   application, and view their information *(Name, Account Status, 
   Ordained, Team number, Calendar of their assigned duty days)*. 
   They can only update their personal info (name, address, 
   phone). Note: The account will be created for users.

2. Director, Asst. Director and System admin can log into the web 
   application (admin dashboard) and see a data table of all users, 
   w/ all relevant fields(view). This group has full read-write 
   privileges.
```

I have a locked table in the model, but not sure if that is the correct way to handle updating a user's status from active to inactive. If inactive, he cannot log into the web application. I would also use this if the user attempts to log-in more the x number of times unsuccessfully. Additionally, it would be helpful (reporting and stats) to keep previous users in the database for x number of years, of course with an inactive status.

Comment: Not sure, why you feel a need for dedicated `locked` table. Column `users.is_disabled` may suffice. Plus, there can be `user_actions` audit table where you can store changes to `users` (or similar table for any entity you need audit).

Comment: Thanks @VictorSorokin for the reply. There is not necessarily a need more so than me, being a neophyte at db modeling, and not sure of best practices... I initially thought an is_diabled column would suffice, but it seemed too simple. Would you give a rudimentary example of a users_actions audit table in conjunction with the users table in the form of an answwer, just so I can visualize? My learning style = visual learner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not using diagram (I don't use diagram tools). Here's extremely basic sample with relevant bits for audit table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id SERIAL,
  -- ...
);
-- ...
CREATE TABLE user_updates_audit (
  audit_id SERIAL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  audit_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL default now(),
  -- just free form text describing applied update (maybe old value, new value, etc)
  audit_text VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE user_updates_audit ADD CONSTRAINT user_updates_audit_pk PRIMARY KEY (audit_id);
ALTER TABLE user_updates_audit ADD CONSTRAINT user_updates_audit_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users;
```

Sure, you may expand from here, for example, by changing free-form `audit_text` to some more strict scheme, e.g. foreign key to dictionary of possible update actions (`ENABLED`, `DISABLED`, whatever) and actual values being changed. Or some other more elaborate scheme more suitable for your case.

But free-form audit is some starting point.

Main value here is that you can see all modifications history of important entities in your system, not just current state.